# php readline string to array

Tags: php, command-line-interface

I tried to find answer but found nothing.
I have php console app which getting console input. This input may be something like

```
array(array($key1 => $val1, $key2 => $val2, $val3), array($val4, $val5, 
$key6 => $val6), ...);
```

and when i'm using readline() for getting input from console i'm get string, of cource, but how can I convert this string in to array without any errors?

Comment: `$arr = array(); $arr[] = readline();` ?

Comment: Can you add a few more details, what would the input be and what do you want the output to look like.  Please also add any code you have so far which sometimes helps clarify the requirement.